# Problems updating my data with MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following class:

```
public class Content
{
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title required")]
    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string ContentType
    {
        get { return PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2); }
    }
}
```

I added the `ContentType` as it's something I need to be able to read (not set). However when I try to save a record I get the following message:

```
The closed type System.String does not have a corresponding ContentType settable property.
```

Did I make a mistake with the way I added the `ContentType` property? What I am wondering is
if I should use a viewModel. But how can I do that? Do I just need to copy each of the properties from my class and add a get and set for each? Plus then just add `ContentType`. 
From what I understand there is a way where I just add the class `Content` to the view model but then I think I would have to change all the `Model.Status` in my views to `Model.Content.Status`. I'd rather just still have `Model.Status` in my views.

What about my checks and display properties. Do I need to replicate them in the viewModel or they just pass through?

Comment: Could you tell us a little more about your scenario? Show your controller and view please? I suspect that the error message you are getting has strictly nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. It happens in your DAL layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model binder needs read-write properties to be able to correctly set the data in your model class.

It uses reflection to set values to properties for a new instance of the type that you declared as your model.